# Как найти K-ый экстремум в списке Python

Tags: python

Всем привет. Задача заключается в том, что задан список, пользователь задает значение К. Нужно найти и вывести K-ый экстремум списка. К примеру, список [1, 2, 3, **4**, 3, 2, **1**, 4, **6**, 2, 10]. K = 3. Тогда 3-им экстремумом будет 6. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать это?

Comment: А если [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 10] -  тогда как? Кто будет третьим экстремумом - 4 или 3?  Как вы вообще определяется "экстремум" для данной задачи? Вас интересует локальный экстремум или глобальный (за прошедшее время)?

Comment: А что, сами даже не попробовали ничего сделать?

Comment: @passant в таком случае 4 будет третьим экстремумом

Comment: @MBo пробовал, конечно. Правда, ничего толкового не получилось. Сам алгоритм предельно ясен, а вот как его реализовать...

Comment: @blvze_bmstu Здесь принято показывать свои попытки. Это повышает шансы на ответ.

Comment: @MBo прошу прощения, я просто новый здесь, на stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

алгоритм простой

1. берете первые 2 элемента списка
2. устанавливаете направление (например `direction = 0` - вниз, `direction = 1` - вверх)
3. дальше идете по всем элементам списка, если элемент меньше/больше предыдущего и не соответствует направлению - это экстремум - меняете направление на противоположное и увеличиваете счётчик экстремумов

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Теперь до меня дошло, смог написать нужный код.